# C++ - Arrays of Pointers, why is it declared this way?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, declaration

not sure how to word the title but hope its some what accurate.

I found this code from a book and I was confused as to why it is declared this way (being new to C++) and what it actually means because the book didn't explain it well and got me more confused:

```
const char * const suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
```

I do not understand the use of 2 const declarations and how an array of strings is actually an array of characters. So if these are c-strings, shouldn't they be of length 4? or because they are pointers, does this just mean it is pointing to the first character of each string?

Just need some one to explain to me what is going on, thank you!

Comment: which book? This looks like C++ from the 1990s.

Comment: Unfortunately things like this are still taught at schools as something you will normally use.

Comment: It is C++ How to Program, eighth Edition by Paul Deitel & Harvey Deitel. It was the one recommended to me and so far it has been good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal is an array in read-only memory (meaning the `char`s in that array are intrinsically immutable). We typically represent C-style strings with a pointer to their first character. For a literal, where the `char`s are `const`, this pointer has type `const char*`.

If you wanted an array of 4 immutable C-style strings, you would declare something like this:

```
const char* arr[4];
```

Each element of this array is a pointer, which you can point at the first character in a C-style string. If you're not going to need to change the pointers in the array themselves, then you can also declare the pointers as `const`:

```
const char* const arr[4];
```

So to be clear, the 4 here is the number of C-style strings we are pointing to. In your case, you have a string for each of the 4 suits in a deck of cards.

Comment: Thank you, that made a lot of sense but do you mean that c-strings without the const are mutable unlike strings? But with const you cannot change them. But I understand the double const declaration now so thank you again.

Comment: @Mayron A `const char*` means you can't modify the `char`s that are pointed at. A string literal, like `"hello"` is an array of `const char`. You can't legally make a `char*` that points to a string literal (because it would allow you to modify the literal).

Comment: okay so a c-string differs because you can use char*? So this is one main reason to use c-strings instead of string literals?

Comment: @Mayron A string literal is an example of a C-style string. It's just an immutable one. A mutable C-style string is represented with `char*`, while an immutable one is represented with `const char*`.

Answer (score 5):

> how an array of strings is actually an array of characters.

It isn't. `suit` is an array of *pointers* to characters. So you have 4 pointers total, each pointing to the first character of the respective string.

Maybe some ASCII art will help?

```
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | H | e | a | r | t | s |NUL|
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       ^
       | +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       | | D | i | a | m | o | n | d | s |NUL|
       | +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |   ^
       |   | +---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |   | | C | l | u | b | s |NUL|
       |   | +---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |   |   ^
       |   |   | +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |   |   | | S | p | a | d | e | s |NUL|
       |   |   | +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |   |   |   ^
     +-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+
suit | * | * | * | * |
     +---+---+---+---+
```

> I do not understand the use of 2 const declarations

The first `const` means the characters won't change, and the second means the pointers won't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char * const suit[4]
```

This says that `suit` is array of 4 `const pointer` to `const char`.